# Where is my map used in my orchestrations?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

We have some maps, orchestrations, schemas and pipelines in this BizTalk project I inherited from a former developer. I'm interested in one particular map's usage.

I don't see any Transform Shapes in the orchestrations. But I know the map is used somehow somewhere in the project.

Where in the orchestrations do I look for the map being used? If not done by Transform shape, is it done via code in a Expression or some other shape? Or could it be done elsewhere outside the orchestration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible and quite common in certain situations to perform a transform in-line in an expression using the `transform()` method within a `Message Assignment` shape:

You can use expressions to dynamic transform messages in your orchestration. XLANG exposes a transform method that can be called from within a `Message Assignment` shape inside of a `Construct Message` shape. This is the same method that is called when a Transform shape is used, but allows you to programmatically transform the messages using the map you designated within the orchestration. This is useful when you are doing type-agnostic message processing. For example, if you have a business process that needs to choose from a series of maps to transform inbound messages based on the parameters provided by the received inbound messages, you can achieve this by using the transform method in the Expression shape while maintaining your overall business process intact.

A sample would look like the following:

```
MyMapType = typeof(MyMapName); 
transform(MyOutputMsg) = MyMapType(MyInputMsg);
```

More information can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa950573.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Map can be used on the ports, both receive port and send port. Choose the port on the BizTalk Admin Console and choose Properties. You see the maps executed on this port.